# leer y cerrar archivo xml

Tags: c#

Estoy utilizando este método para seleccionar un valor de un archivo xml.

El problema es que ese archivo xml es utilizado por otro programa, ese programa me dice que el archivo ya ha sido abierto y no procede a realizar la función. Lo que necesito es que cuando el método tome el valor del archivo xml, lo cierre.

Este es el método:

```
private String getArticleID()

        {
            if (!IsFileLocked(@Properties.Settings.Default.fxml))
            {
                try
                {
                    var inStream = new FileStream(@Properties.Settings.Default.fxml, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
                    XmlDocument documento = new XmlDocument();
                    //string xmlText = File.ReadAllText(xmlpath);
                    //documento.LoadXml(xmlText);
                    documento.Load(inStream);
                    //  documento.LO
                    XmlNode child = documento.SelectSingleNode("Machine/Article/ArticleID");
                    if (child != null)
                    {
                        String val = child.InnerText;
                        return val;
                    }
                    }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Beep();
                    fw.evenLog.WriteEntry("Error_GetArticle " + ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
                    fw.ErrLog += ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + "\n\r";
                }
            }
           return "#";
        }
```

Comment: inStream es lo que debes cerrar. ¿Porqué no utilizas un bloque using para que automáticamente se cierre?

Answer (score 0):

Deberías emplear un bloque `using`   al abrir el `stream`. Este bloque de código loa que hace es un `Close` y un `Dispose` de dicho `stream`.

```
private String getArticleID()
{
    if (!IsFileLocked(@Properties.Settings.Default.fxml))
    {
        try
        {
            using (var inStream = new FileStream(@Properties.Settings.Default.fxml, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                XmlDocument documento = new XmlDocument();
                //string xmlText = File.ReadAllText(xmlpath);

                //documento.LoadXml(xmlText);
                documento.Load(inStream);
                //  documento.LO
                XmlNode child = documento.SelectSingleNode("Machine/Article/ArticleID");
                if (child != null)
                {
                    String val = child.InnerText;
                    return val;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Beep();
            fw.evenLog.WriteEntry("Error_GetArticle " + ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            fw.ErrLog += ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + "\n\r";
        }
    }
    return "#";
}
```